# A simple differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{y}{x}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2+x^2y^2}$$

It will probably be solved using variable separable method but i cant seem to know how? 
source:Higher Engineering Mathematics 44th Edition, B.S. Grewal, 11.2 Q4.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, separate variables after noting that $1+x^2+y^2+x^2y^2=(1+y^2)(1+x^2)$. Hence
$$\frac{ydy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}=\sqrt{1+x^2}xdx$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: just rewrite the equation as

$${y. dy\over \sqrt{1+y^2}}=x\sqrt{1+x^2}. dx$$